# jQuery - if in table tr there is 4 td do something

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm trying to remove any **tr** from **table** that has less than 4 **td** inside.

So for example, in this table I want second tr to go away:

HTML

```
<table>
  <tbdy>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm trying with something like this

jQuery

```
if ($('table tbody tr td').length >= 4) {
  //4 i ok so do nothing
} else {
  $(this).parent("tr").remove();
}
```

But I getting nowhere with this.
Any help?

Comment: Are you using the actual code you posted? Because your first tbody tag is misspelled. You need to change it from `<tobdy>` to `<tbody>`

Comment: I'm not, just for the reference. I've edited the mistake, thanks for noticing :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use jQuery [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector with [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:nth-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) pseudo-class  selector.

```js
$('tr:not(:has(:nth-child(4)))').remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Or alternatively, use [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to filter out element only contains `td` less than 4 and remove.

```js
$('tr').filter(function() {
  return $(this).children('td').length < 4;
}).remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
    var $tr = $(this);
    if ($tr.find('> td').length < 4) {
        $tr.remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, that worked beautifully
edit: sry I gotta go with the crazy selector vote, I love it :)

Comment: No problem. Pranav's solution is far more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Your structure should be :

```
 <table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
```

And you can select it with :

```
$('table tbody tr')
```

To get all tr with less than 4 columns you should loop through them.

Your final code should be :

```
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
    var row = $(this);
    if (row.find('td').length < 4) {
        row.remove();
    }
});
```